# Connect to Snowflake with Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am tasked with rebuilding our Crystal Report files with Snowflake data, as we just transitioned to Snowflake from SQL Server, and am not finding a way to connect to Snowflake.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a connection with the Snowflake JDBC driver? https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1527666
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc.html

ODBC may work as well.